# How to package a java web application

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment, installation

Our company has developed a web application based on Struts2 + Spring + Hibernate.
My boss wants me to make a installation CD contains JRE, Tomcat, MySQL, and our product, so that the client can just click sth like installMe.exe and follow the wizard to complete the installation.
I used to deploy web application with war. Just put it under tomcat webapps folder, and start tomcat.
Which software should I choose to complete my boss's task?
Thanks, guys.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create an installer script and tell the installer where to put the files. I have used two, [advanced installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-simple.html) which creates an MSI or [Nullsoft](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) which is from the guys who created winamp. A lot of open source companies are using it. I'd recommend the fist one, and getting a license to do the more complicated stuff.

The installation of Java is handled automatically with advanced installer. There is even a cool java template you can start from.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'm working on bat file to install the whole thing. I've tried installShield and ext4j, but they are not what I want. I'm going to try your software. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome! Don't forget to accept an answer. We work hard for these points ;)